# Creating a simple executable jar from the Linux command line

Tags: java, linux

I'm trying to create a simple executable jar via my Ubuntu command line from a single java class with a main method. I'm getting a ClassNotFoundException when I attempt to execute the jar though.

I created a file called HelloWorld.java:

```
package hello;
public class HelloWorld {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Hello World");
   }
}
```

I compiled the HelloWorld.java file to HelloWorld.class:

```
$ javac HelloWorld.java
```

Created the executable jar:

```
$ jar cvfe helloWorld.jar hello.HelloWorld.class *.class
```

Then tried to execute the jar but got ClassNotFoundException:

```
$ java -jar helloWorld.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class hello.HelloWorld.class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hello.HelloWorld.class
```

The helloWorld.jar contains HelloWorld.class file and META-INF folder. Within the META-INF folder there is a MANIFEST.MF file.

MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 21.0.2 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: hello.HelloWorld.class
```

I also tried this without specifying the package in the HelloWorld.java file and jar creation command but I got the same exception.

Edit:
Thanks for the responses. It executed correctly when I moved HelloWorld.java into a folder called hello (the package name) and corrected the jar creation command to:

```
$ jar cvfe helloWorld.jar hello.HelloWorld hello/*.class
```

(I had incorrectly wrote the .class extension with the main class name)

Comment: the main class name is **not ** "hello.HelloWorld.class", but "hello.HelloWorld"; if the package is `hello`, that folder must be added to the jar - change the command to `jar cvfe helloWorld.jar hello.HelloWorld hello/*.class` from within the same folder (working directory) that contains the `hello` folder

Comment: Hi @user85421, thank you, this resolved my issue. Do you want to write it as an answer for me to accept?

Comment: All well had you done `javac -d . HelloWorld.java`

Comment: Hi @user85421, would you like to turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: sorry, there are online tutorials about that... and this *site* does not like answers repeating what is already in a tutorial

Answer (score 0):

The Main-Class attribute in your MANIFEST.MF file should only have the full name of the class containing the main method without the .class extension so

updated MANIFEST.MF after jar file is run without .class should look like

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 21.0.2 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: hello.HelloWorld
```

Recreate the jar file without .class

```
jar cvfe helloWorld.jar hello.HelloWorld *.class
```

Try re-executing the jar file again without the .class in the class name and make sure the manifest has been updated as the one above.
This should resolve the ClassNotFoundException issue.

Comment: no need to "update the MANIFEST.MF" - that is done by using the `e` option in `jar cvfe ...`

Comment: Ah yh sorry the steps jumbled just recreate the jar file removing .class as in the second step and make sure the manifest doesnt have the .class as i showed in step 1. Sorry for that but still the step 2 should have no .class like yours did.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I thought you were the OP who replied to my answer, i also had stated the same thing you stated for him to remove the .class from the jar statement and then it would work, my bad.